# Condition on ngx-bootstrap tab for always initializing the component inside it

Tags: angular

How can I put a condition on ngx-bootstrap tab for initializing the component inside it? 
There is no doubt that there are many ways to (show/hide) the component using "active" attribute, but I want to run ngOnInit of the component only when the tab is chosen. The way it is now my component ngOnInit will run even when I did not select the tab.
Somehow `[active]==false` will stop component view from being loaded, but it does not stop its logic behind it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
<tabset #tabset>
  <tab
    heading="First tab"
    ><app-component1 *ngIf="tabset.tabs[0]?.active"></app-component1></tab>

  <tab
    heading="Second tab"
    ><app-component2 *ngIf="tabset.tabs[1]?.active"></app-component2></tab>


</tabset>
```

In ngx-bootstrap tab module you can use the reference of the `tabset` to access the active tab and apply that condition on the component `*ngIf="tabset.tabs[1]?.active"`. This will load the component only when corresponding tab is active.